# Find element with same class

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to find element with same class as different div and add class 'active' to it. So in my example I wanna add class 'active' to '.div-top .same_class-text'.

```js
var theClass = $('.div-bottom div').attr('class');
$('.div-top div').each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass(theClass)) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.main-div, .div-top, .div-bottom {
display:flex;
}
.div-top, .div-bottom {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
}

.div-top {
background:red;
}
.div-top div,
.div-bottom div {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 background:yellow;
 margin:10px;
}
.div-bottom {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
 <div class="div-top">
  <div class="different_class-text1"></div>
  <div class="different_class-tex2"></div>
  <div class="same_class-text"></div>
  <div class="different_class-text3"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="div-bottom">
  <div class="other-class same_class-text"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But your bottom DIV has two classes! Now all depends the logic you want: 1. either one 2. a specific one. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `theClass` contains two classes: `other-class` and `same_class-text`. You can check if a`<div>` contains any of them and then add the class `active` like that:

```js
var theClass = $('.div-bottom div').attr('class');
$('.div-top div').each(function() {
  var classes = theClass.split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    if ($(this).hasClass(classes[i])) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.main-div, .div-top, .div-bottom {
display:flex;
}
.div-top, .div-bottom {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
}

.div-top {
background:red;
}
.div-top div,
.div-bottom div {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 background:yellow;
 margin:10px;
}
.div-bottom {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="div-top">
    <div class="different_class-text1"></div>
    <div class="different_class-tex2"></div>
    <div class="same_class-text"></div>
    <div class="different_class-text3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="div-bottom">
    <div class="other-class same_class-text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not that the class `active` would also be added if a `<div>` contains the class `other-class`.

Answer (score 1):

- The DIV reference has two classes: `"other-class same_class-text"`
- Convert that classes to Array `["other-class", "same_class-text"]` using [String.prototype.trim()<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) and [String.prototype.split()<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- Inside the `.each()` function check if the currently iterating element [`.contains()`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) [`.some()`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of them in its [`classList`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- Than having that boolean value you can use it inside [`.toggleClass()`<sup>jQuery API</sup>](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) (or JS's `classList.toggle`) as the second parameter.

```js
const theClass = $('.div-bottom div').attr('class'); // "other-class same_class-text"
const theClasses = theClass.trim().split(/\s+/);     // ["other-class", "same_class-text"]

$('.div-top div').each(function() {
  const hasSomeClass = theClasses.some(cl => this.classList.contains(cl))
  this.classList.toggle('active', hasSomeClass);
});
```

```css
.main-div, .div-top, .div-bottom { display: flex; }
.div-top, .div-bottom { width: 200px;height: 200px; }
.div-top { background: red; }
.div-top div, .div-bottom div {width: 50px; height: 50px;background: yellow; margin: 10px;}
.div-bottom { background: blue; }

.active {
  outline: 5px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="div-top">
    <div class="different_class-text1"></div>
    <div class="different_class-tex2"></div>
    <div class="same_class-text"></div>
    <div class="different_class-text3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="div-bottom">
    <div class="other-class same_class-text"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Get class of the div you want;

```
var class = document.getElementById("myDIV").className;
```

Set class active to divs with the same class:

```
$("." + class).addClass("active");
```